# How to use combineByKey on dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to achieve secondary sorting in spark. To be precise, for all events of a user session, I want to sort them based on timestamp. Post secondary sorting, I need to iterate through each event of a session to implement a business logic. I am doing it as follows:

```
def createCombiner = (row: Row) => Array(row)

def mergeValue = (rows: Array[Row], row: Row) => {
  rows :+ row
}

def mergeCombiner = (rows1: Array[Row], rows2: Array[Row]) => rows1 ++ rows2

def attribute(eventsList: List[Row]): List[Row] = {
  for (row: Row <- eventsList) {
    // some logic
  }
}

var groupedAndSortedRows = rawData.rdd.map(row => {
  (row.getAs[String]("session_id"), row)
}).combineByKey(createCombiner, mergeValue, mergeCombiner)
  .mapValues(_.toList.sortBy(_.getAs[String]("client_ts")))
  .mapValues(attribute)
```

But I fear this is not the most time efficient way to do this as converting to RDD would require de-serialization and serialization, which I believe is not required when working with dataframes/datasets.

I am not sure if there is an aggregator function that return the entire row

```
rawData.groupBy("session_id").someAggregateFunction()
```

I want the `someAggregateFunction()` to return list of `Rows`. I do not want to aggregate on some columns but want the list of entire `Rows` corresponding to a `session_id`. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, but may not be what you expect. Depends on how complicated your business logic is, there are 2 alernatives other than the combineByKey

1. If you just need mean, min, max and other known function defined in [spark.sql.functions][1]

   [1]: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala you could certainly with groupBy(...).agg(...) . I guess that's not your case. So If you'd like to implement your own UDAF that's no better than the combineByKey unless this business logic is quite common and could be re-used for other dataset
2. Or you need slightly complicated logic you could use window function
   To specify a window spec with Window.partitionBy($"session_id").orderBy($"client_ts" desc) then you could easily implement topN, moving average, ntile etc.See https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html and you could also implement the custom window aggegration function yourself